# Ruler not showing up in .md files in Sublime Text 2

Tags: settings, sublimetext2, markdown, rulers

I cannot make the ruler appear in .md files. The setting `"ruler": [80]` is set in every possible place, including in the Default and User settings of the package Markdown Editing. Yet still, the ruler would not appear. I thought this was a color issue, but even after changing the background of the theme to black, the ruler would not appear. In every other file type the ruler appears. What other settings could I check?

Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you turn the ruler on from the drop down menu?

Comment: Same thing - nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option's name is `rulers` here (although I am using sublime 3), so `"rulers": [80]` should work.

Comment: Yes, indeed the name of the option is `rulers`, not `ruler`.